# Disable keyboard shortcuts in GTKTreeView

Tags: gtk, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, gtktreeview

I have a problem with the keyboard navigation is my TreeView. I haven't found a solution to this in the documentation.

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp/Down</kbd> keyboard combination has a default meaning when a TreeView has focus. The thing is that I want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp/Down</kbd> for something else so I have to somehow disable this keyboard command.

Preferable I would like to capure this key combination so that no widget in the window ever receives this.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent an event from being sent further just return TRUE in your event handler then you have consumed the event.